# Using multiple textures for shader programming in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, textures, shader

I'm currently using TextureObjects when reading in a texture. I read in two textures, and want to dynamically switch between them, but when I try do:

```
tUnit =(\(TextureObject x) -> x) texObj
```

And then

```
activeTexture $= (TextureUnit tUnit)
setUniform p "texUnit" (TextureUnit tUnit)
```

It doesn't work, but if I replace tUnit with 0, it works but it'll draw everything with the last texture I load.

I'm using GLUtil's `readTexture` function to load in my texture.

Any thoughts?

Comment: um, `tUnit =(\(TextureObject x) -> x) texObj`? why? `tUnit (TextureObject x) = x`. Also, texture unit IDs aren't texture object IDs.

Comment: Ah, that'd work too, lol. Sorry, I'm not quite used to Haskell yet. Yeah, but I'm not sure how to pass a TextureObject as a uniform variable, and I can't find anything on it. I don't get the difference between them?

Comment: Figured it out, I'm dumb! Posted an answer explaining what I did wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextureUnit is a local shader id and the TextureObject is a global texture id. I wasn't binding my TextureObject again before setting the active texture, so it was just using the latest one bound.